# Why can't tmux read the session file when ran from PHP?

Tags: php, linux, bash, shell, tmux

I want to create a PHP site which can manage multiple sessions and read contents from them. So in order to realize this I decided to use `tmux` with the PHP `exec()` command.

The sessions will run under the user `www-data`, each running their separate task.

I use the following code to get a list of all running sessions in PHP:

```
$command = "tmux -S /tmp/tmux-33/default ls";
$command."<br>";
exec($command . " 2>&1", $output, $result_code);

$output = JSON_Format($output);
echo "$output<br>";
```

And that echoes

```
tmux -S /tmp/tmux-33/default ls
[ "no server running on \/tmp\/tmux-33\/default" ]
```

That would mean that the file does not exist, right?
Well no. That's because If I open the terminal and run

```
sudo tmux -S /tmp/tmux-33/default ls
```

Than the output would be

```
0: 1 windows (created Sat Mar  9 18:09:34 2024)
2: 1 windows (created Sat Mar  9 18:16:42 2024) (attached)
```

Even reading the file with nano outputs `[ Error reading /tmp/tmux-33/default: No such device or address ]`, which proves the file exists.

And I can confirm that `tmux-33` corresponds to `www-data`, because If I don't provide the -S parameter, It default to that file.

Another thing I tried to confirm that `www-data` is properly configured is connecting to It's shell directly as follows:

```
codrut@Linux-Server:/tmp$ sudo -u www-data -s /bin/bash
www-data@Linux-Server:/tmp$ tmux list-s
0: 1 windows (created Sat Mar  9 18:09:34 2024)
2: 1 windows (created Sat Mar  9 18:16:42 2024) (attached)
www-data@Linux-Server:/tmp$
```

So clearly the two sessions can be read by the apache account, but not from PHP with `exec`. I tried `shell_exec` as well, but that provided the same result.

It also seems [the user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30714276/php-tmux-and-screen-dont-behave-correctly-no-launch-no-new-session-no-new-win) superfuzzy also had this issue. For them, downgrading to PHP 7.1 fixed the error. I am running PHP 8.3.3-1. Unfortunately, I cannot afford to downgrade to an older version, as much of my website infrastructure relies on new functions introduced in PHP 8.

The user superfuzzy also noticed the following

> Another weird thing: when launching the tmux sessions over php the terminal has no user and no location
> Normally it looks like user@machinename$ ...
> With php it just looks like $ ... nothing more

And after a bit of digging, I found that this is caused by the fact that Apache2 uses '/bin/sh' as the shell. Which in Ubuntu, does not default to '/bin/bash' but to '/bin/dash', which from my understanding is a more lightweight and faster version of bash with a little less features. But from my testing, this should not affect tmux in any way.

I also tried creating a `test.sh` script and then executing `/bin/bash` on the script. The script is as follows:

```
#/bin/bash
echo "test script"
tmux ls
```

And the output:
[ "test script", "no server running on /tmp/tmux-33/default" ]

So is there anything I can do, or maybe some alternatives to the `exec()` function? I'd really appreciate some advice.

Thank you.

Comment: php has native support for threads and fibers now, which will make this much easier. A server library like amphp (there are others as well) gives you abstractions to simplify the task further.

Comment: @Jerry But how will threads change the problem? I need to run a shell command and read Its output. Tmux to be exact

Comment: I thought you were using tmux to manage concurrent processes. I guess my answer would depend on what it is you are trying to do with tmux.

Comment: What's the purpose of `$command."<br>";`?   I can't see that it is doing anything, so it's likely not responsible for the error either, but for the safe side I would just remove the line.

Comment: Another change I would do, because it could simplify debugging, is to write a shell script which congains the tmux command, and call this from PHP. Once you have a shell script, it is kind of a self contained box, and you can add various debugging commands easily (for instance a `ls -d /tmp/tmux*`).

Comment: @user1934428 the `echo $command` was just a line I added for debugging to see if the command was properly read, which it was. And I tried adding tmux in a bash script and running that one, but It still did not work.

Comment: From what you posted, my guess is that during the time your PHP program was executing, there was indeed no tmux server running. I would put into your test script something like `pstree; uname -a`, to see what's going on on that host. Another thing to consider is, whether the PHP program runs under the same user id than the user who presumably started the tmux session. Therefore, a `who am i` in your script also wouldn't harm.

Comment: @user1934428 `whoami` returns the correct user. I can be completely sure that sessions were running while I ran the PHP program and It's unable to create new sessions, which proves that the PHP session somehow prevents tmux from running correctly.

Comment: I don't know the details of your PHP program, but can you start an interactive shell (i.e. one which has a tty/pty allocated) from your program? I am not sure that `tmux` can work reliably if you are not interactive. To test it the other way round: Since the command works from your interactive shell, do the same not from PHP, but from a shell script which does not have a tty. See the accepted answer [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1430872/how-to-simulate-a-shell-without-tty).